# Let $a,b > 0$, and consider the interval $(a,b)$. Let $a < x_0 < b$. Prove that (a,b) is a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b > 0$, and consider the interval $(a,b)$.  Let $a < x_0 < b$.  Prove that (a,b) is a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Proof:
Assume $a,b>0$ and $a < x_0 < b$.  Let $\epsilon = \frac{b-a}{2}$.  Then consider the interval  $(x_0-\frac{b-a}{2}, x_0 + \frac{b-a}{2})$. Then $(x_0-\frac{b-a}{2}, x_0 + \frac{b-a}{2}) \subset (a,b)$.  Thus $(a,b)$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Please let me know if I am going about this correctly.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the right general idea, but I think you've chosen the wrong expression for $\epsilon$.  With the $\epsilon$ that you chose, there's no guarantee that $(x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$ is entirely within the interval $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $a=1$, $x_0=2$, and $b=5$? then $\epsilon=2$, but $(2-2,2+2)=(0,4)\nsubseteq(1,5)$. You need to take $\epsilon$ small enough to make sure that $x_0-\epsilon\ge a$ and $x_0+\epsilon\le b$. Your idea of splitting a distance in half is good, but the distance that you should be splitting is the smaller of $x_0-a$ and $b-x_0$.

Comment: So it has something to do with $\epsilon = min\{x_0 - a, b - x_0\}$ ? Is that small enough though?

Comment: @tkrm: It is; try a few numerical examples or, better yet, make a couple of sketches to convince yourself, then try to show it algebraically.

Comment: Alright I will. Thanks.

Comment: @tkrm: If you get stuck, or just want me to check what you’ve done, give me another ping.